# Galaxy S4's LCD broken. How do I access hidden folders in the storage using computer?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, file-system, broken-screen

I recently broke my screen entirely so the touch function and LCD do not work at all on my Samsung Galaxy S4.  I managed to plug in a keyboard to my phone to input my pass-code in order to unlock the phone so I could access the files on the computer.  However, I do have some files on my phone that are hidden (with the `.` file prefix I used to hide them in a separate file manager app).  I can not figure out how to access these files.  I am willing to download any program necessary to get these off my phone!

Again I can not use my phone at all as the screen is broken.  Possibly if I can remotely control the phone via my computer?  Any help is appreciated.  If absolutely necessary I will have to replace the digitizer and LCD.

Answer (score 1):

As you're able to access your device (i.e. apply input to it), the easiest option would be activating [usb-debugging](/questions/tagged/usb-debugging) and then use [adb](/questions/tagged/adb). There are even good graphical remote-tools when it comes to ADB (if the device is rooted, and your computer is running Windows, I strongly recommend taking a look at [Droid Explorer](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer); its dev is an active member here at this site), but you can as well deal with the command line (`ls -a` would include hidden folders and files in a listing of the directory you're in).

For additional hints, please take a look at our tag-wikis for [broken-screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) and [adb](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info), plus at my [list of ADB tools](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_adb) – the latter including pointers to several "ADB file-managers" which might prove helpful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I can't comment to ask what PC OS you're using, so I guess I'll assume it's Win7. So open an instance of Windows Explorer.
Then, select "Folder and search options".
Select the tab marked " View".

On the "Hidden files and folders", select the radio button " show hidden files,folders,and drives".
Also, your phone isn't on charge only, is it? If it is, I'm afraid I can't be much of assistance there..